# Loading bar in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to show a loading message/icon until all the items in the list have been rendered.

Here is the jsfiddle with my example: http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/58/

I've tried to add a div with a loading bar in the Feed section, but it doesn't work.

How can I show a loading message before all the book views are rendered in the book list view:

```
app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.feed',
    initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you need to `fetch` some content asynchronously from somewhere to display the loader. A **loading** is needed to show the user that you are actually fetching the content and that the UI is not dead.
In that fiddle even if you got it working you won't be able to see it because the collection is bootstrapped and you are not fetching anything.

This simulates that ([updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R9zU/59/)):

```
app.BookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.feed',
    initialize: function() {
      this.loader();
      this.listenToOnce( this.collection, 'sync', this.render); // or listenTo ?
      this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook );

      // this simulates the fetching...
      // It's not really needed
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){
          self.collection.trigger('sync');
      }, 3000)

    },
    loader: function(){
        this.$el.html('<div>Loading...</div>')
    },
  render: function() {
        this.$el.empty();
    this.collection.each(function( item ){
      this.renderBook( item );
    }, this);

  },
  renderBook: function ( item ) {
    var bookview = new app.BookView ({
      model: item
    });            
    this.$el.append( bookview.render().el );
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aJfUx/1/**

```
render: function() {
    // Make this loading icon/message whatever you want
    this.$el.html("<i class='icon-spin icon-refresh loading-icon' />");

    this.collection.each(function( item ){
        this.renderBook( item );
    }, this);
    this.$el.find(".loading-icon").remove();

}
```

And here's an example that uses `setTimeout` to artificially add some loading time so you can see that spinner spin!

http://jsfiddle.net/7ddXM/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the fiddle works perfectly but in my real code when is put the this.$el.find(".loading-icon").remove(); it doesn't work. I need to check out if there is another problem with my code.

Comment: I still don't know which is the problem with my real code. When I insert this.$el.html("<p class='loading'>LOADING</p>"); without this.$el.find(".loading").remove();, the Loading message shows at the top of the page and after the render goes to the bottom of the page. But when I insert this.$el.find(".loading").remove();, it doesn't even appears at the top of the page, and in the console I don't see any error. I already tried this.$el.find(".loading").css({display:none});, and in the console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: none is not defined . What could be the problem??

Comment: I expect that it's just being removed before you get a chance to see it (see my first demo vs. my second). Your original post didn't specify where the delay is coming from, or why you need a loading bar. Rendering a sensible number of elements isn't likely to take a noticeable amount of time.

You're getting that exception because you need to specify the *string* `"none"` (with quotes). `none` is not a special keyword, and it's not a variable you have defined. The object you pass to `.css()` looks like, but isn't a slab of css code; it's JSON.

Comment: In my real code the delay is coming form the Firebase, because I'm using Backfire to store the data, and I want to prevent the user of seeing how it's built the renderbook. My goal is to show a loading message while all the data is rendered and remove the loading message only after the render.

Comment: Do you have some suggestion to loading message while all the data is rendering?

Comment: We'd need to see the code to answer properly, but the short answer is to set the `html()` of `this.$el` to the loading message when you start loading the content, and `remove()` that loading message at the end of the `render()` function.

Comment: I've done that, but the problem is that the loading message is removed before all the content is ready, and the users see the images rendering

Comment: You will need to post your current code to get help with that.

Comment: Here is the Fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/aJfUx/5/. At the beginning it shows the loading message, but the views start rendering at the top of the loading message, and the loading message goes to the bottom of the page until the end of the rendering (after that is removed).

Comment: That Fiddle doesn't work for me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collection' of undefined`

Comment: That's because I didn't included the real Firebase Collection

Comment: Ok, I'm going to include my real Firebase Collection

Comment: The reason you don't see the waiting message is because the rendering (of books elements) haults the DOM from showing the changes. When the books are rendered only then it starts to show the waiting msg and books element but that is too late and then the msg is removed by the last line.