# Loading message with Backfire and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backfire

I'm trying to insert a loading message/icon while Firebase (Backfire) is serving my backbone app with data, but it's now working well, here is a fiddle with a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/aJfUx/5/

I tried to add and remove a HTML element when I'm rendering the data, but it doesn't work:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html("<i class='icon-spin icon-refresh loading-icon' />");
    this.collection.each(function( item ){
    this.renderBook( item );
    }, this);
    this.$el.find(".loading-icon").remove();
}
```

My goal is to only show all the data only after everything is rendered.

Comment: Your example throws an error

Comment: Thanks for the message. I'm not showing my real Firebase collection, the fiddle It was only to show all the code logic.

Comment: Why do you ask the same question multiple times? I see this being asked for at least two more times (one post was closed). Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624907/loading-bar-in-backbone Why don't you go from there and expand on the answers?

Comment: Sorry but the question wasn't clear so I needed to reframe the question and I thought that creating a different question would give some different answers comparing if I only edit the other question.

Comment: If you're just fishing for different answers, you should encourage a discussion in just one thread and make people aware of what you don't like about their answers. People are spending (wasting) time to respond to your questions as they think you have a genuine problem.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that `renderBook` takes a long time and you try to prevent the user seeing how it's built. I'd create a element and populate it without it being part of the DOM yet.

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html("<i class='icon-spin icon-refresh loading-icon' />");
    var $panel = $('<div></div>');
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
      this.renderBook(item, $panel);
    }, this);
    this.$el.html($panel);
}
```

Comment: Yep that's my problem. Do you suggest that the render part should be this? render: function() {
        this.$el.html("<i class='icon-spin icon-refresh loading-icon' />");
        var $panel = $('<div></div>');
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
              this.renderBook(item, $panel);
        }, this);
        this.$el.html($panel);
 }

Comment: In `renderBook()`, you'd need to use the `$panel` variable, instead of `this.$el` (`$panel.append( bookview.render().el );`). That's the easiest I can come up wih without changing too much of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the renderBook() should look like this? renderBook: function ( item ) {
  var bookview = new app.BookView ({
   model: item
  });            
  $panel.append( bookview.render().el );
 }. Unfortunately it doesn't work, the console shows this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $panel is not defined

Comment: Are you sure that `this.$el.html("<i class='icon-spin icon-refresh loading-icon' />");` will be applied to the DOM (and thus visible to the user) while `render` is still running?

Comment: That's the problem, I want the icon to stay visible until the end of the render and only in that moment to show all the data rendered

Comment: You're right. `this.$el` is the view's element. It's not actually part of the DOM yet. You could could run render() twice. First time, you'd return an `el` and then, upon an event such as `sync`, you could build your book list. You could use the collection's size as indicator for whether or not to draw the icon (if empty, you draw the loading icon, else you create this list). You would need to pass an empty collection to the view, render it and update the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to try to do what you suggest.

Comment: Can you show me a fiddle with your suggestion? I'm having problems doing that. THanks

Comment: What do you have trouble with?

Comment: Is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aJfUx/7/? I think I'm missing some part

Comment: Indeed. This isn't doing anything, but displaying the static html.

Comment: Ok, so what I need to change?